# Javascript: accessing multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a new set of arrays from an existing array, using the code:

```
var stock = new Array()
    for (i = 0; i < seOutput.length; i++) {
      stock[i] = new Array(seOutput[i][0], seOutput[i][1], seOutput[i][2], seOutput[i][3], seOutput[i][4])      
}
```

If I `console.log(seOutput);` I see this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
      (
          [0] => Blue
          [1] => Yes
          [2] => No
          [3] => Yes
          [4] => Yes
      )

  [1] => Array
      (
          [0] => Red
          [1] => No
          [2] => No
          [3] => No
          [4] => Yes
      )
```

This worked logically in my head, where the code `seOutput[0][0]` would equal `Blue`, but that's not what's given back in my `console.log(seOutput[0][0]` statement.  For the statements `console.log(seOutput[0])` and `console.log(seOutput[0][0])` I get `A` (the first letter in the word `Array` ).

What is the proper way to access this array?

To give a bit more detail, `seOutput` is generated from my ajax success call to a .php page where the final bit of code is:

```
foreach ($json['Result']['Data']['Type'] as $i) {

  $y = "{$i['Color']},{$i['Object']},{$i['Crs']},{$i['CrsX']},{$i['CrsB']}"; 
  $x = explode("," , $y);
  array_push($output, $x);
}
```

then

```
print_r($output);
```

and my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
              url: "seSearch.php", 
              type: "post",                  
              data: {partNumber: q , c:c},
              success: function(data) {

                  var seOutput = data;
  }
});
```

What's generated from that is the "array" I pasted above.  Why ajax has converted this into a string I don't know....

Comment: what array are you trying to access? `seOutput` or `stock`?

Comment: `stock` is built from `seOutput`, and the `for` loop works, it just doesn't populates with bogus data because I'm not referencing `seOutput` correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you assigned string to `seOutput` (containing array string representation) instead of real array in. So you access it properly but you have no array.
Try print `typeof(seOutput)` to check it.

Comment: `string` - that's weird.  So I don't even have an array here.  Is there a simple way to convert this into an array?  (Also, aside from that, was my logic on how to access this if it WERE an array correct?)

Comment: Yes, the code is correct IF it was an array. how are you building the array?

Comment: I don't know where you get this string. But there must exists original array before conversion to string. Maybe you accidentally make conversion somewhere.

Comment: you need http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
instead of print_r().

Also set header Content-Type: application/json
to proper parsing in $.ajax

Comment: how silly of me... yeah, doing json for both solved it.  Thanks @farincz